# Camera App Wont Start

Tags: windows-10-mobile, camera

I have an issue with my windows phone (Windows Phone 10 / Microsoft branded hardware).

The camera software won't start. I hit the camera button from the start menu, and the app begins to load, the loading screen is there for some time, and then I get sent back to the start menu. The camera software never loads.

My guess is that the camera app is taking to long to load.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your device? Have you tried other camera related apps like camera360 sight, blink, etc and faced same problems?

Comment: restarted the device - not tried other apps tho

Comment: Have you plenty of free space on your device/SD card?

Comment: loads of free space on the phone - ive put about 1Gb of music on it, there is at least 14+ Gb of free space

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue, and found by holding volume down and power together helps, but isn't 100% successful.

I've found it can happen to any app, due to them not being updated along with new updates.

This is especially a problem with windows 10 phone technical preview.